# OnItemClick nor for all elements

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclick

I've got a `ListView` with 31 Items.
You can click on the first 30, but not on the last one.
To handle the Click Event, I use an `OnItemClickListener`.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    if(position!=30) {
        //The Code wich is Run for the first elements
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when you click on the last element, something happens, and I'm not able to figure out, what exactly. How can I disable the reaction to a click on this element?

Comment: try to debug,,,print `position and array size first and use` **if(position!=array.size()-1){ }**

Comment: "something happens, and I'm not able to figure out, what exactely." - Specify this thing.

Comment: The Listview has a TextView and an ImageView in each Row, if you click on the last element, some of the Images above disappear and appear aggain while scrolling...